# Extracting chinese subtitle from video

Tags: image-processing, ffmpeg, video-processing, subtitle, pyffmpeg

Given a video like:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cNHeiIM5xZI

Is there any library or tool that supports extraction of subtitle?

Extraction of subtitle in sequence would be sufficient, it would be plus if it can extracts the timestamp as well.

Comment: There are tools that can extract `subtitle` data, but linked video doesn't look like having subtitle data. Those are just bitmap pixels. IMHO going to OCR way will be more fruitful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Stroke Width Transform](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=149305) to find the bounding box of all (horizontal) text in each frame. If the position and size are suitable then you can assume it is the subtitles.
The processed frame number will give you the time-stamp relative to the beginning.